# Android Studio CardView element returns Null

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-cardview

I have a file called `row_list.xml` which holds the style of a CardView. This CardView is the root object of this xml file. I'm using this `CardView` in a `RecyclerView` in my `activity_main`.

**row_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        //codes>

        <TextView
            //codes />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

In my `MainActivity.java` I want to get the current height of this CardView, and then use this height for something. But when I call the code below, I got `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.getHeight()' on a null object reference`.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CardView cardView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cardView = findViewById(R.id.card_view);

    System.out.println(cardView); //prints null

    int height = cardView.getHeight(); //I get "null" object error
```

Why does `cardView = findViewById(R.id.card_view)` returns null? How can I get the attributes of a CardView? Couldn't find a related question/solution on the web.

Edit after comment

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list,parent,false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
```

Comment: `cardView = findViewById(R.id.card_view)` comes from  `row_list.xml` and your activity layout is `activity_main.xml`

Comment: `cardView = findViewById(R.id.card_view)` should be in Adapter section

Comment: you need to  declare and calculate the height of cardview in the related adapter class.

Comment: @Tausif could you give an example how to do that? I can share the part of the adapter that is related to that .xml file

Comment: Please share your adapter class

Comment: @Tausif

Here the part related to that .xml

`@NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list,parent,false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }`

Comment: Please add this code in Question

Comment: @Tausif

Just edited.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232684/discussion-between-tausif-and-glhf).